# How to create an interactive pdf file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, browser

I want to create dynamic pdf files and embed initials and signature to them inside browser. I found pdfkit.org but I need a more comprehensive solution that allows creating functionalities similar to what you see in docusign. Are there solution out there that you can point me to?

Comment: As per my knowledge with Javascript alone you cannot achieve the interactive feature. Even I had the same requirement where I was supposed to convert html to pdf which should be interactive. I just used this "evopdf" converter tool which is actually a .net service. You pass the html and you get the pdf output.

http://www.evopdf.com/


But for your requirement i think pdfkit.org suits more better than EVOPDF

Answer (score 1):

From farther research, I learned that PDF & Javascript are good friends. The easiest way to achieve manipulating content within a pdf is to convert it to html, add the changes to it and then convert it back to pdf. There are a few different services available that help you with this kind of conversion. Here are a few of those services:

- https://cloudconvert.com
- http://www.pdfonline.com/
- https://market.mashape.com/netservice/convert-pdf-to-html